# Complete reset of a git repository

Tags: git

I have a git repository in which I have made quite a few changes, and pushed to a remote location.

I wish to reset the repository to the 3 commit from the first, push it to the remote branch. I'm considering doing the following :-

- git reset
- git push origin master

A couple of doubts regarding the same?

- Would this be the right way to do it?
- I have deleted certain files and added a few files after the 3rd commit(from the first). I wish to change all that back to the state of the 3rd commit(get back the deleted files, remove the newly added ones). How could I go about doing that?

Thanks.

[EDIT]
I'm a solo developer on this project at this point in time. Also there are quite a few commits made so Id rather not manually have to revert each one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already sent your files to a remote repository, it is not a good idea to perform a `git reset` because other developers should updated their local repositories and get the new updates. The best solution is to perform a `git revert`, a command that generates a new commit that undo what a previous commit did. For more information, take a look at this [link](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html).

But if you were the only developer of this project, you can delete the commits. For this, you can use the `git reset` command:

```
git reset --hard hash
```

where hash is the commit hash that you want to return. The option `--hard` is to almost complete remove the commits after the commit hash you passed.

As you were changing the project history, you can't perform a simple `push`. You will need the flag -f to force the update:

```
git push -f origin master
```

However, some remote repositories have some [hook](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html) that prohibits you to force update the history. You will need to delete this hook to allow you to perform a history update. If you can't do this, you will need to use the `git revert` command.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't mentioned this earlier but ill update the question with this info : I'm the only developer at this point, and there are quite a few reverts to make so I'd rather do it in a single shot. Are there any options that you'd suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
git reset --hard <3rd commit>
```

to get all files back and remove the newly add ones.

Then use

```
git push -f origin master
```

to force update the remote.

Comment: A "git pull --rebase" seems to be what is suggested in most places, however, that would pull the changes I had just deleted.

Comment: @uki Did you set `receive.denyNonFastForwards` to `true`, this will reject `git push -f`